# How do I autostart a tmux bash script as a startup service in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, tmux, systemctl, ubuntu-23.10

I used to run a TShock server on a Raspberry Pi 4. I've recently gotten more powerful hardware, an Intel "Skull Canyon" NUC6i7KYK with a new installation of Ubuntu 23.10, and I'm trying to replicate my server setup with `systemd` instead of `init.d` and `rc.local` like I did on the Pi.

I'm looking for the best method to start the server inside `tmux` during system startup, as my current strategy of starting it as a bash script run via a service might be overcomplicating things. Here's my current approach:

I have a shell script here that runs the server:

`/home/terraria/start-server.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/kokonoe/terraria/tshock/TShock.Server -config /home/kokonoe/terraria/serverconfig
```

Another shell script that starts the server in a `tmux` session, split-screened with `htop`:

`/home/terraria/autostart.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
export DOTNET_ROOT=/home/kokonoe/terraria/tshock/dotnet  # this is normally set in ~/.bashrc, but systemctl doesn't seem to see it there.
tmux new -s tshock -d "/bin/bash /home/kokonoe/terraria/start-server.sh"
tmux split-window -h "htop"
tmux last-pane
```

These two scripts work well in a terminal session and will start the server as expected. However, I'm struggling with writing a `systemctl` service to start the server on startup. I have a .system file here:

`/etc/systemd/system/terraria-autostart.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs TShock in a tmux session.

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/kokonoe/terraria/autostart.sh
User=kokonoe
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then `sudo systemctl start terraria-autostart`. What I *expect* to happen is for a `tmux` session to get created, split horizontally, with `tshock` on the left and `htop` on the right, like what happens when I run `~/terraria/autostart.sh`, but instead, I only see `htop` and nothing else, so the server script exited and closed its pane.

I suspect some weirdness with environment variables or `PATH` or something, but I'm not sure where to start poking, or if a service is even the best way to implement a start-up script. Thanks for the look!

Comment: Wrapping the service inside tmux seems like a serious [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why would you run a service inside an interactive terminal multiplexer?

Comment: I suppose, ultimately, I'm looking for a good way to start this server in tmux on startup, and I thought a one-shot service was the way to go as I've used it for similar things before. If there's a more straightforward / canonical way of achieving a start-up script for an interactive terminal I'd defer to that.

Comment: To restate the question I interpret tripleee as having asked: Why do you need the service to be _in an interactive terminal_? Even without the terminal you can use journalctl to read its output. If you need to write commands to it on its stdin, then you can tell systemd to wire that stdin to a FIFO or socket. I don't know the details of terraria, but for _most_ services it's only stdout and stderr that matters, stdin in rare cases, but pretty much never `/dev/tty`.

Comment: For my use case, it would be for inputting administrative commands to the TShock server, so the interactive terminal is valuable to me. It sounds a little like a service isn't the thing I'm looking for, so I'm wondering where I should place something like this?

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering with setting environment variables, such as sourcing `.profile` and `.bashrc`, running it via services wasn't panning out. However, running the script as a `cron` job via `@reboot` eventually worked as expected. I have no idea how the two differ in terms of their environments, but mayhaps this can help a future gamer!

Comment: This was the solution I would have suggested as well. If it's your personal toy in your personal home directory which you personally want to interact with, a system service is probably not what you want.